# pdo insert slow performance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im experiencing an issue with a method i created to insert data in three different tables of a database, it is too slow, and is not inside a loop i need help to detect what the problem is... here is my code.

```
public function procesaOrdenRun () {
     #trae variables de config
    $data      = new Config();
    $base_path = $data->url();
    $base_path = str_replace("/classes","",$base_path);

    $fecha_creado    = date("Y-m-d");
    $fecha_entrega   = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fecha_creado. ' + 7 days'));

    $id_paciente     = $_POST["id_preregistro"];
    $estado          = "6";
    $asignado        = $_POST["dr_remitente"];
    $precio          = $_POST["precio_plantilla"];

    $tipo_plantilla  = $_POST["tipo_plantilla"];
    $tipo_pie        = $_POST["tipoPie"];
    $observaciones   = $_POST["observaciones"];

    $id_usuario   = $_POST["id_usuario"];

    $id_plantilla   = $_POST["id_plantilla"];

    $consecutivo = $_POST["consecutivo"];

    //$archivo_fresado = $_POST["fresado"];
    //$archivo_presion = $_POST["presion"];

    //die(var_dump($_FILES["fresado"]["name"]));

    $archivo_fresado = "../files/".$_FILES["fresado"]["name"];
    $archivo_presion = "../files/".$_FILES["presion"]["name"];

    $target_dir = "../files/";
    $target_file1 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fresado"]["name"]);
    $target_file2 = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["presion"]["name"]);


    if (!empty($_FILES["fresado"]["name"])){

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fresado"]["tmp_name"], $target_file1)) {
            //echo "El archivo ". basename($_FILES["fresado"]["name"]). " se ha subido correctamente.";
        } else {
            echo "Error al subir el archivo ".$target_file1;
        }

    }

    if (!empty($_FILES["presion"]["name"])){

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["presion"]["tmp_name"], $target_file2)) {
            //echo "El archivo ". basename($_FILES["presion"]["name"]). " se ha subido correctamente.";
        } else {
            echo "Error al subir el archivo ".$target_file2;
        }

    }

    //die(var_dump($archivo_fresado));

    $facturado       = 0;

    $db   = new database();
    $conn = $db->conn();

    try {

        $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ortomec_orden_pedido (
                            id_paciente,
                            fecha_entrega,
                            estado,
                            asignado,
                            precio,  
                            tipo_plantilla,
                            tipo_pie,
                            archivo_fresado,
                            archivo_presion,
                            observacion,
                            id_usuario,
                            fecha_creado,
                            facturado,
                            id_plantilla,
                            consecutivo
                            )
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        $query->bindParam(1, $id_paciente);
        $query->bindParam(2, $fecha_entrega);
        $query->bindParam(3, $estado);
        $query->bindParam(4, $asignado);  
        $query->bindParam(5, $precio);
        $query->bindParam(6, $tipo_plantilla);
        $query->bindParam(7, $tipo_pie);
        $query->bindParam(8, $archivo_fresado);
        $query->bindParam(9, $archivo_presion);
        $query->bindParam(10, $observaciones);
        $query->bindParam(11, $id_usuario);
        $query->bindParam(12, $fecha_creado);
        $query->bindParam(13, $facturado);
        $query->bindParam(14, $id_plantilla);
        $query->bindParam(15, $consecutivo);

        $query->execute();
        //return true;

        //self::updateOrder(); //se agrego para que actualice el orden de las ordenes de pedido y asi funcionen las flechas con las que se "ordenan"

        $this->updateOrder(); //se agrego para que actualice el orden de las ordenes de pedido y asi funcionen las flechas con las que se "ordenan"

        } catch( PDOException $e ) {

        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

        return false;

        }    


    $idOrden = $conn->lastInsertId('id_orden_pedido');

    /*$sql = "select max(id_orden_pedido) from ortomec_orden_pedido";
    $query = $conn->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll();

    $idOrden = $results[0]["max(id_orden_pedido)"];*/





    /* Actualiza aqui */

    $bmi1               = $_POST["bm1Izq"];
    $bmi2               = $_POST["bm2Izq"];
    $bmi3               = $_POST["bm3Izq"];
    $bmi4               = $_POST["bm4Izq"];
    $bmi5               = $_POST["bm5Izq"];
    $bmd1               = $_POST["bm6Izq"];
    $bmd2               = $_POST["bm7Izq"];
    $bmd3               = $_POST["bm8Izq"];
    $bmd4               = $_POST["bm9Izq"];
    $bmd5               = $_POST["bm10Izq"];

    $derechaIzquierda = $_POST["clickEleve"];

    $selectCmp          = $_POST["selectCmp"];

    $botonMetatarsianoIzq = $_POST["botonMetatarsiano"];
    $botonMetatarsianoDer = $_POST["botonMetatarsiano2"];

    $elevacionDer       = $_POST["elevacionDer"];
    $elevacionIzq       = $_POST["elevacionIzq"];

    $almohadillaEscaDer = $_POST["almohadillaEscaDer"];
    $almoadillaEscaIzq  = $_POST["almoadillaEscaIzq"];
    $cuniaExternaDer    = $_POST["cuniaExternaDer"];
    $cuniaExternaIzq    = $_POST["cuniaExternaIzq"];
    $cuniaInternaDer    = $_POST["cuniaInternaDer"];
    $cuniaInternaIzq    = $_POST["cuniaInternaIzq"];


    try {

        $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ortomec_orden_correctores (
                                idOrden,
                                bmi1,
                                bmi2,
                                bmi3,
                                bmi4,  
                                bmi5,
                                bmd1,
                                bmd2,
                                bmd3,
                                bmd4,
                                bmd5,
                                selectCmp,
                                botonMetatarsianoIzq,
                                botonMetatarsianoDer,
                                derechaIzquierda,
                                elevacionDer,
                                elevacionIzq,
                                almohadillaEscaDer,
                                almoadillaEscaIzq,
                                cuniaExternaDer,
                                cuniaExternaIzq,
                                cuniaInternaDer,
                                cuniaInternaIzq                                
                            )
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        $query->bindParam(1, $idOrden);
        $query->bindParam(2, $bmi1);
        $query->bindParam(3, $bmi2);
        $query->bindParam(4, $bmi3);  
        $query->bindParam(5, $bmi4);
        $query->bindParam(6, $bmi5);
        $query->bindParam(7, $bmd1);
        $query->bindParam(8, $bmd2);
        $query->bindParam(9, $bmd3);
        $query->bindParam(10, $bmd4);
        $query->bindParam(11, $bmd5);
        $query->bindParam(12, $selectCmp);
        $query->bindParam(13, $botonMetatarsianoIzq);
        $query->bindParam(14, $botonMetatarsianoDer);
        $query->bindParam(15, $derechaIzquierda);
        $query->bindParam(16, $elevacionDer);
        $query->bindParam(17, $elevacionIzq);
        $query->bindParam(18, $almohadillaEscaDer);
        $query->bindParam(19, $almoadillaEscaIzq);
        $query->bindParam(20, $cuniaExternaDer);
        $query->bindParam(21, $cuniaExternaIzq);
        $query->bindParam(22, $cuniaInternaDer);
        $query->bindParam(23, $cuniaInternaIzq);

        $query->execute();

        /*var_dump($query);

        die(var_dump("idOrden ".$idOrden,"bmi1 ".$bmi1,"bmi2 ".$bmi2,"bmi3 ".$bmi3,"bmi4 ".$bmi4,"bmi5 ".$bmi5,"bmd1 ".$bmd1,"bm2 ".$bmd2,"bmd3 ".$bmd3,"bmd4 ".$bmd4,"bmd5 ".$bmd5,"selectCmp ".$selectCmp,"botonMetatarsianoIzq ".$botonMetatarsianoIzq,
        "botonMetatarsianoDer ".$botonMetatarsianoDer,"elevacionDer ".$elevacionDer,"elevacionIzq ".$elevacionIzq,"almohadillaEscaDer ".$almohadillaEscaDer,"almoadillaEscaIzq ".$almoadillaEscaIzq,"cuniaExternaDer ".$cuniaExternaDer,
        "cuniaExternaIzq ".$cuniaExternaIzq,"cuniaInternaDer ".$cuniaInternaDer,"cuniaInternaIzq ".$cuniaInternaIzq));*/

        //return true;

        } catch( PDOException $e ) {

        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

        return false;

        }    



    try {

        $completoAlta = $_POST["completoAlta"];
        $superiorMedia = $_POST["superiorMedia"];
        $superiorBaja = $_POST["superiorBaja"];
        $descargaTalonBaja = $_POST["descargaTalonBaja"];
        $descargaTalonAlta = $_POST["descargaTalonAlta"];
        $diagonalBaja = $_POST["diagonalBaja"];
        $diagonalMediaSuperior = $_POST["diagonalMediaSuperior"];

        $id_orden_uso = $_POST["id_orden_uso"];
        $detalleUso = $_POST["detalleUso"];
        $longitud_plantilla = $_POST["longitud_plantilla"];
        $tipoCalzado = $_POST["tipoCalzado"];

        $completoPosicion = $_POST['completo'];



        $superiorArriba = $_POST['superiorMediaRa'];
        $superiorAbajo = $_POST['inferiorAltaRa'];

        $descargaAbajo = $_POST['descargaTalonAltaRa'];

        $superiorInferiorAlta = $_POST['diagonalMediaSuperiorRa'];
        $superiorInferiorBaja = $_POST['diagonalAltaRa'];

        //die(var_dump($superiorInferiorAlta, $superiorInferiorBaja));

        //die(var_dump($diagonalMediaSuperior, $diagonalMediaInferior, $));


        $query = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO ortomec_orden_disenio_durezas (
                                idOrden,
                                completoPosicion,
                                completoAlta,
                                completoMedia,
                                superiorArriba,
                                superiorAbajo,
                                superiorMedia,
                                superiorBaja,  
                                inferiorMedia,
                                inferiorAlta,
                                descargaAbajo,
                                descargaTalonBaja,
                                descargaTalonAlta,
                                descargaTalonMedia,
                                superiorInferiorAlta,
                                superiorInferiorBaja,
                                diagonalBaja,
                                diagonalMediaSuperior,
                                diagonalMediaInferior,
                                diagonalAlta,        
                                uso,
                                detalleUso,
                                longitud,
                                tipoDeCalzado
                            )
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');

        $query->bindParam(1, $idOrden);
        $query->bindParam(2, $completoPosicion);
        $query->bindParam(3, $completoAlta);
        $query->bindParam(4, $completoMedia);
        $query->bindParam(5, $superiorArriba);
        $query->bindParam(6, $superiorAbajo);
        $query->bindParam(7, $superiorMedia);  
        $query->bindParam(8, $superiorBaja);
        $query->bindParam(9, $inferiorMedia);
        $query->bindParam(10, $inferiorAlta);
        $query->bindParam(11, $descargaAbajo);
        $query->bindParam(12, $descargaTalonBaja);
        $query->bindParam(13, $descargaTalonAlta);
        $query->bindParam(14, $descargaTalonMedia);
        $query->bindParam(15, $superiorInferiorAlta);
        $query->bindParam(16, $superiorInferiorBaja);
        $query->bindParam(17, $diagonalBaja);
        $query->bindParam(18, $diagonalMediaSuperior);
        $query->bindParam(19, $diagonalMediaInferior);
        $query->bindParam(20, $diagonalAlta);
        $query->bindParam(21, $id_orden_uso);
        $query->bindParam(22, $detalleUso);
        $query->bindParam(23, $longitud_plantilla);
        $query->bindParam(24, $tipoCalzado);

        //die(var_dump($query));

        $query->execute();
        //return true;

        } catch( PDOException $e ) {

        echo 'Caught exception: ', $e->getMessage(), "\n";

        return false;

        }    


}
```

here i attach the create script for all the tables:

```
    delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `orden_pedido` (
  `id_orden_pedido` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_paciente` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_entrega` date NOT NULL,
  `estado` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `asignado` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `precio` double(16,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_plantilla` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipo_pie` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archivo_fresado` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archivo_presion` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `observacion` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_creado` date NOT NULL,
  `hora_creado` time NOT NULL,
  `facturado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `fecha_abierta` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_diseno` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fecha_produccion` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `id_plantilla` int(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orden` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_modificacion` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `adicional` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `consecutivo` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_orden_pedido`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=388 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$


delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `orden_correctores` (
  `idCorrector` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idOrden` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `bmi1` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmi2` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmi3` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmi4` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmi5` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmd1` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmd2` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmd3` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmd4` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `bmd5` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `selectCmp` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `botonMetatarsianoIzq` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `botonMetatarsianoDer` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `derechaIzquierda` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `elevacionDer` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `elevacionIzq` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `almohadillaEscaDer` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `almoadillaEscaIzq` varchar(255) DEFAULT '0',
  `cuniaExternaDer` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `cuniaExternaIzq` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `cuniaInternaDer` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  `cuniaInternaIzq` int(2) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idCorrector`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=313 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$

delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `orden_disenio_durezas` (
  `idDisenioDurezas` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idOrden` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `completoPosicion` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completoAlta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `completoMedia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorArriba` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorAbajo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorMedia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorBaja` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inferiorMedia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inferiorAlta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descargaAbajo` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descargaTalonBaja` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descargaTalonAlta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descargaTalonMedia` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorInferiorAlta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `superiorInferiorBaja` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diagonalBaja` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diagonalMediaSuperior` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diagonalMediaInferior` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `diagonalAlta` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uso` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `detalleUso` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitud` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tipoDeCalzado` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idDisenioDurezas`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=313 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: WHAT is too slow? a particular insert? all of them? You are also simply assuming file uploads will never fail - bad idea.

Comment: Hi. 

when i call the method, it takes something like one minute to do all that stuff. Thanks for your observation ill fix that aswell.

Comment: so figure out which of the queries is slow. `$start = microtime(true); ... do query stuff ..; $end = microtime(true); echo $end - $start;`

Comment: please come back with those metrics. nice to know :>

Comment: And add the create table for both used tables please + index model on those (show index from table).

Comment: There's a lot of code, but just quickly scanning through it, I don't see anything that looks like an obvious source of slowness. If you execute the same queries without involving PHP (using MySQL workbench or the command line) are they still slow?

Comment: No other indexes? What is the size of the tables (in mln of records) and the load on the database system?